# Not sure what this DVI-like port on my PC is

Tags: dvi, connector, compaq-desktop-computer

I have a re-manufactured HP Compaq dc7700p Small Form Factor running Windows XP (for some reason inside the Windows Vista Boot Manager, instead of the WinXP NTLDR).

On the back of my PC, I have what looks like a DVI Port, and that's what I thought it was. When I bought a DVI to VGA Cable (to connect a second screen), it wouldn't fit. I took a look and found that the DVI connector was different to the port on my PC. I would love to post some pictures, but being a new user, I can't.

[image]
What I want to know is what port this actually is, so that I can find a suitable converter.

The only difference between this and DVI is at the end with the 4 square pins and the +-shaped pin. The + pin is still there, but instead of the 4 dots, I have two flat lines underneath the squares (above the +), which are of the length of 2 of the squares.

Comment: You can upload the picture somewhere and Psy a link. Someone with image posting rights can post it then

Comment: I have just updated with a description. Does this help? (Thanks for the quick reply!)

Comment: @Hennes - The front is the same, but the back is completely different. I will try and link to an image of it:  http://sdrv.ms/VeeE1Y (My DVI Cable: http://sdrv.ms/VeeGXC )

Comment: General comment:  My cable is DVI-I, and my PC has DVI-D (Dual link) but with those two lines you can see (thanks @Hennes!)

Comment: Your DVI cable has a bent pin.

Comment: @KyleJones - It is a new cable - which one is bent?

Comment: Looking at the photo it should be obvious.  If you can't see it in the real cable then I must be mistaken.

Comment: Is this a better image? https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=245843B2122C0CFE!1418&authkey=!AHMQiM38tDs7ebI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, a DVI to VGA cable will **not** work without the two pins above and two pins below the "bar" or "plus"; that is what carries the analog signal

Comment: How can someone down vote that? It's true...

Answer (score 5):

Looks like DVI-D to me too. Maybe [this cable](http://www.i-tech.com.au/products/16864_DVI_D_Dual_Link_Extension_M_F_Cable.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Comment: You're correct. This is DVI-D (digital video only). He can't use a DVI-to-VGA cable. (The two extra slots are to allow VESA PnD connectors to fit. They're not connected to anything.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your PC has a DVI output. Please notice that the DVI standard has different plugs, depending on the type of data that is sent through the cable (it could be both digital or analog). Refer to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) to see which port your PC has.

Comment: None of the diagrams in section 2 are the same as mine - all of them have C1,2,3 & 4. Mine has C5, but not 1,2,3 or 4. Instead of C1-4, it has the 2 lines I mention.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the specification for that connector, but probably it should work with a DVI-D (single or dual link) cable. Even if the cable has less pins than the plug it should work. For example, you can plug a DVI-D cable into a DVI-I plug and it will work, because the DVI-I connector carries both digital and analog signals.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely DVI-I vs DVI-D.

Take a look at [this super user question](https://superuser.com/questions/390178/dvi-d-vs-dvi-i-is-the-digital-video-quality-any-different) that shows both (granted, a different question with similar answers).

Yours sounds like DVI-D single link.

Comment: Afraid not - take a look at these: http://sdrv.ms/VeeE1Y (on PC) and http://sdrv.ms/VeeGXC (on Cable)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's DVI-I as was suggested by others. Check out http://www.playtool.com/pages/dvicompat/dvi.html

[image]

Comment: rather, the slot is DVI-D and the cable you have is DVI-I.

Comment: more pins than holes!